# My Ipv6 is under attack by the smurf6?

Tags: attacks, vpn

When I go to whatsmyip.org under my host name I get "Your.Ipv6.Is.Under.Attack.By.The.Smurf6.Info". What does this mean? I'm using private internet access as my VPN so I'm guessing PIA is under some sort of attack? What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

As @bonsaiviking commented, this is a form of DNS Registry Spam, and unfortunately it is very easy to do. The upside is, it's not an attack on your domain, and it shouldn't cause anyone actual problems (unless you are trying to sift through DNS records...)

The example of google.com given at the [razzed.com](http://razzed.com/2009/01/15/at-first-i-thought-google-was-being-hacked/) link is as follows:

> whois google.com
>
> Whois Server Version 2.0
>
> Domain names in the .com and .net domains can now be registered
>   with many different competing registrars. Go to http://www.internic.net
>   for detailed information.
>
> GOOGLE.COM.ZZZZZ.GET.LAID.AT.WWW.SWINGINGCOMMUNITY.COM
>   GOOGLE.COM.ZZZZZ.DOWNLOAD.MOVIE.ONLINE.ZML2.COM
>   GOOGLE.COM.ZOMBIED.AND.HACKED.BY.WWW.WEB-HACK.COM
>
> ...many lines left out
>
> GOOGLE.COM
>
> To single out one record, look it up with "xxx", where xxx is one of the records displayed above. If the records are the same, look them up with "=xxx" to receive a full display for each record.